# Connecting Windows Service with Web Api?

Tags: api, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I currently have a website(reactjs) and an asp.net core api. Right now All the end points in my core api are protected by "Authorization" Tags. A user will log in and a token/refreshed token will be issued and this will be sent each request.

Now I am building an windows service that needs to access my database. I don't really think it is a good idea for this service to have direct access to the database and I think it might better to have one end point that has access to the database(ie the web api).

This now leads me to figure out how will my windows service connect to my api. The only way I can figure is to make a fake user that will login and then each time my service needs to connect to the api it would send that token.

Otherwise I guess I would have to make some sort of api keys or something?

Comment: What are you using to authenticate the users? IdentityServer? Could you use [ClientCredentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#client-credentials) to authenticate the service with the API?

Comment: I am using asp.net core identity.

Comment: What did you end up doing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

So if we are talking solutions - id offer you a proposed one below.

The real issue is making sure your core api understands that the incoming request is valid without having to restructure the API too much in its current form.

Your idea with API Keys is something I would look at doing , you could write a middleware inside your API that will read the Api key from the headers sent by the windows service,verify it and then generate a valid JWT token and add it to the request headers. Once that request gets to the MVC layer it will contain a valid JWT token and pass the Auth header .

This introduces complexity by having to maintain a set of API Keys inside a database though and validating them on a request level. That means every request sent will have to go through this process and do a DB lookup for keys.

To alleviate this I would add another header that indicates that the incoming request comes from another source other than the user(checked in middleware) and perhaps add a caching implementation over the set of api keys to keep them in memory to reduce lookups.

The above scenario would be useful if your windows service needs to do the exact same thing a user does.

If its different logic nothing stops you from rolling a new controller with bespoke endpoints for your service with its own authorization policy that you can define for that controller. That controller will then be responsible for servicing the windows service ( or other components).

Comment: Yea, I think API Keys is the way to go but right now we don't have immediate plans to open up our api to external applications so it would all just be for this service so I am not sure if it is at this time worth the amount of work it would seem to do. With making a new controller and have it's own policy might be the option but I would not know what the checks would be to make sure it really is the servce would be.